# How to compare column values in different dataframes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, compare

I have found this code , and it is working very well.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1, 4, 7], 'c2': [2, 5, 1], 'c3': [3, 1, 1]})
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c4': [1, 4, 7], 'c2': [3, 5, 2], 'c3': [3, 7, 5]})
 set(df1['c2']).intersection(set(df2['c2']))
```

But I need to compare them with multiple column names like

```
set(df1['c2']['c3']).intersection(set(df2['c2']['c3']))
```

But it is not working. How to fix or what is another way to compare them and find similar values ( matches ) ?

Comment: you'll need to merge - if you have a large matrix it might be easier to melt the dataframe into a more tabular form then merge on a single column as opposed to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `merge` follow by `drop_duplicates`

```
df1.merge(df2,on = ['c2','c3'])[['c2','c3']].drop_duplicates()
```